# ActiveJob queue limiting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

Seems that the task is simple and straightforward: I need to limit amount of jobs that can be performed at the same time, so my server won't blow up. But google is silent, perhaps I'm doing something wrong? Enlighten me please?

I use standard async adapter.

Comment: It depends on what backend (queue adapter) you're using, really. For example, with `sidekiq`, you can limit max number of concurrent jobs by simply setting workers count.

Comment: @MarekLipka I don't wanna overcomplicate it, so i use default rails async adapter

Comment: So it's async adapter by default in Rails 5, so it's kinda limited by the number of threads and you can limit it further, like described here:
https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/AsyncAdapter.html
Also, as this piece of documentation says, it's not very good choice for production environment to stick with the default adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not recommended to use default rails async adapter in production, especially for heroku dyno that restart itself once per day.

> For enqueuing and executing jobs in production you need to set up a
>   queuing backend, that is to say you need to decide for a 3rd-party
>   queuing library that Rails should use. Rails itself only provides an
>   in-process queuing system, which only keeps the jobs in RAM. If the
>   process crashes or the machine is reset, then all outstanding jobs are
>   lost with the default async backend. This may be fine for smaller apps
>   or non-critical jobs, but most production apps will need to pick a
>   persistent backend.

There are plenty of supported adaptor to choose from such as:

- Sidekiq
- Resque
- Delayed Job

It's easy to start, they provide clear instruction and example.

Comment: While this is indeed 'Enlighten' wrt running active jobs in production, it does not answer the main question. How could one limit the number of running jobs when using the default async adapter (e g.in development).

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the default async adapter in development and would like to limit the maximum number of jobs that will be executed in parallel, you can add the following line in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = ActiveJob::QueueAdapters::AsyncAdapter.new min_threads: 1, max_threads: 2, idletime: 600.seconds
```

So in this case at most two will run at the same time. I think the default maximum is twice the number of processors.

I have a case where I need to limit it to one and that works just fine (Rails 7).

Source: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveJob/QueueAdapters/AsyncAdapter.html